# SQL Server 2005: Job scheduled every 4 hrs, but sp_help_jobactivity shows unexpected value for next_scheduled_run_date

Tags: sql-server

I have done a lot with sql and jobs, and this is throwing me off.

My job is scheduled as shown below.

I can run the job interactively from SSMS by starting the job, it runs, all is well.

It is currently Jan 27 at 11 AM local time.
But sp_help_jobactivity returns a next_scheduled_run_date of

next_scheduled_run_date
2012-01-27 12:01:00.000

I expect it to be four hours from the last time I ran it, or from when I created the job and schedule (which I created at the same time).

**Observed Problem:** While the SSMS GUI displays "12:01 AM" the data in next run shows "12:01:00" which is "12:01 **PM**"

What am I missing?
When will the job next run?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Uhh... the GUI is showing you the start / end times (in case you need / want to only allow a job to run during certain times).  The next run time was correct (12:01 PM) considering that the job would run @ 12:01A, 4:01A, 8:01A, 12:01P, 4:01P, 8:01P each day and it's currently 11A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job runs every 4 hours starting with the start time in the schedule. If you run it manually that has no effect on the next scheduled startstart time.

Answer (score -1):

OK, the above comments are the story. Basically, the GUI is not very clear.

As stated, when you set a job to run every 4 hrs, with a start time of 12:01 AM, then SQL works out the sequence of 00:01, 4:01, 8:01, 12:01 PM, and so you see the 12:01 PM.

There does not seem to be a way to say "every four hours, starting now and every four hours thereafter"

The issue could be solved with a GUI improvement so that the GUI simply spells out what is going to happen.